# How can I update the firmware on a DWM-156 HSUPA 3.75G USB adapter?

Tags: updates, firmware

I am using DWM-156 HSUPA 3.75G USB ADAPTER.Its hardware version is A6 and Firmware version is 6.0.0WW.I have purchased the modem one month back.Using this i am not able to receive call or make call.

One my friend purchased the same product recently.He is able to receive call and make call.His Firmware Version is 6.0.0IN.Is any body know how can i update it or is any other option?

Comment: Sadly, I think you'll need to use a windows machine (oh well, just borrow a friends windows computer). Most things related to firmware must be done on windows.

Answer (score -1):

You can download the software from [this site](http://www.dlink.com.my/support/support_detail.asp?idProduct=512). It's available in the Support+Downloads tab.

Comment: But *how* does one install that firmware?

Comment: By following the instructions on their site? Which also state that you'll need a windows install to do the upgrade.